# Javascript localStorage unshift array stops appending after two items

Tags: javascript, arrays, html, local-storage

I have a javascript function that fires on page load. My goal is to store a json string in localStorage like this `"item1","item2","item3"` using the unshift method to build this in an array one item at a time.

This is what my function looks like here:

```
function storedItems (){
    var modelItem = $('#item').html(),
        modelInt = $('#int').html();

    if (localStorage.modelItem || localStorage.modelInt) {

        var itemStack = [],
            intStack = [],
            itemStorage = localStorage.getItem("modelItem"),
            intStorage = localStorage.getItem("modelInt"),
            itemHistory = JSON.parse(itemStorage),
            intHistory = JSON.parse(intStorage),
            item = JSON.stringify(itemHistory).split(","),
            int = JSON.stringify(intHistory).split(",");
        alert("History " + item + " " + int + " " + item.length + " " + int.length);

        if (item.length > 0) {
            for ( var i = item.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                var obj = item[i],
                    newItem = JSON.parse(obj);

                if(item.length > 1 && item.length < 3) {
                    itemStack.unshift(newItem);
                    itemStack.unshift(modelItem);
                    alert("StringFinder 2 " + modelItem + " " + itemStack);
                } else {
                    newItem.unshift(modelItem);
                    alert("StringFinder 2 " + modelItem + " " + itemStack);
                }
            }
        }
        if (int.length > 0) {
            for ( var i = int.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                var obj = int[i],
                    newInt = JSON.parse(obj);

                if(int.length > 1 && int.length < 3) {
                    intStack.unshift(newInt);
                    intStack.unshift(modelInt);
                    alert("StringFinder 2 " + modelInt + " " + intStack);
                } else {
                    newInt.unshift(modelInt);
                    localStorage.setItem("modelInt", JSON.stringify(newInt));
                    alert("StringFinder 2 " + modelInt + " " + intStack);
                }
            }
        }
        localStorage.setItem("modelItem", JSON.stringify(itemStack));
        localStorage.setItem("modelInt", JSON.stringify(intStack));
        alert("StringFinder 4 " + itemStack + " " + intStack);
    } else {
        localStorage.setItem("modelItem", JSON.stringify(modelItem));
        localStorage.setItem("modelInt", JSON.stringify(modelInt));
    }
}
```

I can get this result `"item1","item2"` , but if it fires a third time the script fails after the first History alert fires. I am basically stumped. I have been searching for solutions, and working with some others trying to figure it out without success. Please, help in any way you can.

Comment: once you have parsed to array no need to use JSON.parse again on elements of array. Think of it as you only use JSON methods to store and retrieve from/to localStorage , then you are working with native script arrays/objects

Comment: @charlietfl For some reason, when I choose not to stringify the parsed json I get an item/int length for each character instead of each string. Therefore I tried to parse it again in order to unshift it properly to the array. Is there a better way to get the length of the array without every character being counted?

Comment: I suggest you start the logic over and remember that after you parse from localStorage you have an object or array. So you don't need things like `item = JSON.stringify(itemHistory).split(","),` If in doubt , can use `typeof` to check.

Comment: What I mean is that it counts each letter (example: the result for item.length would be 4 instead of 1) when it is parsed.

Comment: that part makes no sense, `intHistory` has just been parsed from JSON string to array but then you reverse it to get `item`. In the end you should have less code than you do now

Comment: You're not understanding me, and what I understand from you is that you want me to parse only when getting from storage, and stringify when setting. Okay, but I need to get and item count and I can't achieve the results I'm looking for if each letter is counted instead of each string. I have tried exactly what you're telling me to do numerous times already. Please, I have spent days on this issue now. If what you are saying were true anyway, I would not have achieved these results "item1","item2".

Comment: then something is wrong in your data or data structure. I have used localStorage many many times. Create a demo in jsfiddle.net that replicates your problem

Comment: @OnlineOverlord charlietfl is absolutely right. There is way too much parsing and stringifying going on here. You should stringify values as you are putting them into localStorage, and parse values as you are taking them. That's it. This is definitely wrong: `itemHistory = JSON.parse(itemStorage), ... item = JSON.stringify(itemHistory).split(","),` You are parsing _something_ (looks like it's an HTML string?) and then immediately turning it back into JSON and splitting it by comma (and then later parsing the individual pieces). What??? You shouldn't be manually deconstructing JSON values.

Comment: I've been spending 15 minutes trying to make sense of what you are trying to do here and I still can't. Please simplify your example to include _either_ `item` or `int` (since they seem to be independent of each other), tell us what kind of values are in `#item` (or `#int`), and most of all, _explain_ what it is that you are trying to do. When in doubt: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Please, I get it about the parsing. Like five comments ago I asked how I can get item.length to equal 1 instead of 5. If I can get that result then I wouldn't have tried stringifying and parsing all over again. Every question I ask on here I end up having to figure it out on my own but like weeks later. I wouldn't come here if it were as simple as everyone looks at it to be.

Comment: I made an example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/senatorlaw/wftnsjfy/2/). If you click run again that should try to get the key values item and int. Once it gets them you'll see an alert that shows the value difference of item and itemHistory. It explains exactly what I'm trying to do in the alert. Hence, the reason why I am doing the forbidden and parsing and stringifying a second time. If somebody can help me to get the result of 1 instead of 5 without parsing and stringifying again please let me know. So far I'm being told what not to do and it isn't helping.

Comment: @OnlineOverlord I am fairly sure that your inability to get a decent answer here is due to your inability (or rather, unwillingness) to ask a decent question. Please read the mcve link I posted for future reference. If you had been willing to debug and simplify your code to the essence of the problem, 80% of the code in your post could have been omitted and you would have had an answer hours ago.

Comment: The hint to your problem is in the first line of the question - _My goal is to store a json string in localStorage like this `"item1","item2","item3"`_ - and there's your problem - that's not a legal JSON string.  It would have to be enclosed in `[ ... ]` to make it a legal JSON **array** of strings.

Answer (score 2):

The cause of the bug you are experiencing is here:

```
localStorage.setItem("modelItem", JSON.stringify(modelItem));
localStorage.setItem("modelInt", JSON.stringify(modelInt));
```

You are JSON-encoding and storing string values in your local storage, so when you take them out of local storage and parse them, they are still strings, not arrays.

You need to store them as arrays in the first place:

```
localStorage.setItem("modelItem", JSON.stringify([modelItem]));
localStorage.setItem("modelInt", JSON.stringify([modelInt]));
```

I have gotten your code into a working state and you can try it out here:

http://jsfiddle.net/5qad1nwe/1/

For future reference, as I pointed out a few hours ago, if you want a decent answer here, you have to distill your problem to its essence. In many cases, this act of reworking and simplifying the code will often allow you to solve the problem on your own without having to ask.

**Here is an example of how you could have asked this question and gotten a quick answer (and possibly upvotes)**

---

I am having trouble storing and retrieving values in localStorage. When they are not yet defined in localStorage, I store the values for the first time (they are just regular string values without much importance), and then the next time I access them from localStorage I want to retrieve them as an array, copy its contents to another array along with another value, and re-store the values:

```
var modelItem = $('#item').html();

if (localStorage.modelItem ) {
    var itemStack = []
        itemStorage = localStorage.getItem("modelItem"),
        itemHistory = JSON.parse(itemStorage);

    console.log("itemHistory.length is " + itemHistory.length);

    for (var i = 0; i < itemHistory.length; i++) {
        itemStack.unshift(itemHistory[i]);
    }

    itemStack.unshift(modelItem);

    localStorage.setItem("modelItem", JSON.stringify(itemStack));
} else {
    localStorage.setItem("modelItem", JSON.stringify(modelItem));
}
```

However, the first time I load the data from localStorage, `itemHistory.length` is not 1 as I expected but actually a larger value. What am I doing wrong?

---

Comment: Thank you for this, but it didn't work for me. You did point me in the right direction though. Here is the [jsfiddle with my solution](http://jsfiddle.net/senatorlaw/wftnsjfy/3/). It is a lot less code than before now. I do understand my mistake. I appreciate you both taking time out to help me understand my bug. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution to my own answer. My apologies for the confusion. I simplified and fixed it here.

```
var modelItem = $('#item').html();

if (localStorage.modelItem) {
itemStorage = localStorage.getItem("modelItem");
itemHistory = JSON.parse(itemStorage);
alert(itemHistory.length);

if (itemHistory.length > 0) {
    if(itemHistory.length < 3) {
        itemHistory.unshift(modelItem);
        alert("StringFinder 2 " + itemHistory);
    } else {
        itemHistory.unshift(modelItem);
        itemHistory.pop();
        alert("StringFinder 3 " + itemHistory);
    }
}
localStorage.setItem("modelItem", JSON.stringify(itemHistory));
alert("StringFinder 4 " + itemHistory);
} else {
var itemStack = new Array();
itemStack.unshift(modelItem);
localStorage.setItem("modelItem", JSON.stringify(itemStack));
}
```

[Here is the most recent JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/senatorlaw/wftnsjfy/3/)